# Local Mailbox Move Exchange 2010

Tags: email, exchange-server-2010

Can someone explain the exact process of archive mailboxes in EMC when you run a local Mailbox move request from one database to another.

Are the files copied first and then deleted from the source if the move has failed / destination has changed? or are the files directly moved so no longer found from the source address during and after the move?

Background: we are running low on space on one of the exchange archive databases and require the archives to be moved to a new database.
When trying this first the destination (the drive the database was pointing to) was wrong and needed to be changed. We then removed the new database and re-created pointing to the correct network drive.

Looking at the old destination there is 28GB of archive data on there, are we able to just copy and paste the archives to the correct network drive? or will the files become corrupt as its being copied by File explorer?

Thanks
Alex Hawkins